# Save Workspace in Fortran

Tags: fortran, save, intel-fortran

Is there anyway to save a workspace in Fortran? Specifically in Intel Fortran. For example in Matlab I can do:

```
for i=1:n
  %some stuff here
end

save workspace

for j=1:n1
  %some stuff here
end
```

So if I want I can comment out the first part of the code, load the workspace and run only the second loop.

I was wondering if there was something similar in Fortran.

Answer (score 3):

No, Fortran is too low-level for this. There is no such a feature. You must develop some custom way, how to save all your data and program state, yourself. It is often quite complicated.